# access db and sql server 2008 express how do i link them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is it possible for someone to connect

`microsoft access database`
 to
 `sql server 2008 express`

i want to view the tables of the access database in ms server and i also want to make queries like

`CREATE UPDATE JOINS`

but i am failing how to do it,any ideas?? or books i can read i have been browing online but i am not getting a straight forward answer...i want to make 
`queries and view tables from the sql  server`

thanks alot

Comment: Access is best for retrieving data from sql, not updating the structure.

Comment: so can not do it the other way??

Comment: It might work, but I think access would refuse it because it only passes on queries it understands.. if you want to do that you'd do better to talk to SQL direct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an Access database accDB, and I recommend you avoid using a Data project (ADP).

You then simply link to the existing tables in the server database.

As for wanting to execute any server side command from inside of Access?

Just create a pass-through query in Access.

You can then size this window however you want, and you can type in any SQL server commands into that window.

In fact you can type in multiple commands and run them all at once.

So, for example these 3 SQL statements run + work fine in Access as a pass-though.

[image]

So, in above, you can not only see we executing server side commands, but as noted, you can enter multiple commands and even scripts if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Version of Access: 2007
Version of SQL Server: 2008

Microsoft Access is not guaranteed to be upward compatible, so this is expected.
It was the same story with Access 2003/SQL Server 2005.

See [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917418) for workarounds - the primary of which is doing DML via Access VBA.

Comment: The recommend setup when using Access to SQL server is to use open database connectivity. That means that using Access 97 (now 15 years old), or the BRAND NEW version of Access 2013 will work fine with the NEWEST version of SQL server. So for what silly reason would you suggest some compatibility exists here when you can use a 15 year old version of Access with the most current version of SQL server? ADP's for Access have been depreciated for Access 2013, and use of ADP is not recommend for Access connecting to sql especially now that oleDB support for SQL server is being depreciated also.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is asking about the linked tables/queries designer, which is kept compatible up to the current version of SQL Server at the time of Access release. If you're using modules, that's no different from using VBA. I could be wrong though.

Comment: The Access table designer can ONLY be used on SQL server tables if they create what is called a ADP (access data project). ADP's are depreciated for Access 2013. Only ADP had issues and required matching of Access version to SQL server version. Using the now recommend linked table manager and Open Database connections, then version sensitivity does not exist. Using Open Database connection means you cannot use Access table designer on SQL server table structures. You either use SSMS or as my screen shot shows you can use the Access SQL builder (not the code editor) and send SQL DDL commands.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with Access 2013. Access Data Projects are superior to linked tables.. because you only have to maintain the connection in ONE PLACE.  Jet isn't really maintainable when you start linking to different ODBC connections, don't forget to check the connection strings on the SQL passthrough queries.. those aren't fixed when you change a connection via Linked Table Manager.